# Intermittent `PusherRequestError` with status code 400 when using `pusher.trigger()`

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pusher, pusher-js

### Description

We are using `"pusher": "^5.1.3"` in our `RealtimeService` and are occasionally experiencing an error when triggering events. This is a `PusherRequestError` with status code 400, which suggests that the request made by the `pusher` library to the Pusher API is failing.

Here's the complete error stack trace:

```
Error: 
    at new RequestError (/app/packages/server/node_modules/pusher/lib/errors.js:13:16)
    at /app/packages/server/node_modules/pusher/lib/requests.js:61:17
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at RealtimeService.publish (/app/packages/server/src/core/services/realtime/realtime.service.ts:30:13)
    at AssetService.updateQueueProgress (/app/packages/server/src/modules/asset/asset.service.ts:415:9)
    at AssetService.setCompleted (/app/packages/server/src/modules/asset/asset.service.ts:380:23)
    at AssetWebhookHandler.handleAssetProcessingComplete (/app/packages/server/src/modules/asset/webhooks/webhook.handler.ts:827:29)
    at AssetWebhookResolver.handleAssetProcessingComplete (/app/packages/server/src/modules/asset/webhooks/webhook.resolver.ts:430:13) {
  name: 'PusherRequestError',
  message: 'Unexpected status code 400',
  url: 'http://api-eu.pusher.com/apps/1614183/events?auth_key=APP_KEY&auth_timestamp=1689415586&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=3cfafa3985dfd22ca3fa4a08ccbe2621&auth_signature=ef83ac3eb82a3c553333387f8cfe8d9e858caf9cde41a11b99f7ab942e56df7b',
  error: undefined,
  status: 400,
  body: 'Invalid JSON provided (could not parse)\n'
}
```

This error occurs sporadically and it doesn't appear to be related to the payload being sent with the trigger. We've also tried reinstalling the `pusher` package, but this has not resolved the issue.

Here is the relevant method in the `RealtimeService` where we trigger the events:

```js
class RealtimeService {
  private pusher: Pusher;

  constructor() {
    const {
      PUSHER_APP_ID,
      PUSHER_APP_KEY,
      PUSHER_APP_SECRET,
      PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    } = process.env;

    this.pusher = new Pusher({
      appId: PUSHER_APP_ID,
      key: PUSHER_APP_KEY,
      secret: PUSHER_APP_SECRET,
      cluster: PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
      useTLS: process.env.NODE_ENV as string !== 'local',
    });
  }

  public async publish<E extends Events>(channel: Channels, userId: string, event: E, data: EventPayload[E]) {
    try {
      console.log(`Publishing ${event} to ${channel}.${userId}`, data);
      await this.pusher.trigger(`${channel}.${userId}`, event, data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}

export default RealtimeService;
```

And this is an example of a payload being sent:

```
Publishing UPLOAD_PROGRESS to NOTIFICATIONS.4d63e01f-82f8-4584-9e4b-7708e04764dc { failed: 0, completed: 5, processing: 1, queued: 1, total: 7 }
```

```
Publishing JOB_COMPLETED to MIGRATIONS.ONLY_ADMINS { jobId: '08903cd9-1237-4fe4-8d58-2997dbb5b388' }
```

Any help or insights into why this may be happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out what was causing this? Having the same issue.

Comment: Yup, go to the issue I created for an update. https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-node/issues/195